# Getting Page ID and Access Token to post to Fan Page as Application

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-page

After a day with google and lots of testing what is out there at the moment, I cannot find a definitive answer on this, in light of the depreciation of the offline_access request within the facebook api.

What I am trying to achieve is to update the fan page wall for my application as the application itself with the output of an RSS feed my main site is generating (Im not too worried about reading/parsing RSS part at this stage, I think I have that cracked). As things stand at the moment I can post to the fanpage wall, but the posts are appearing as if from my personal profile (which is an Admin of the fan page).

The application I've created is for my use ONLY and for the purpose of writing to my fan page wall. I've tried using third party tools (RSS Graffiti/Twitter Feed) but they just dont meet my requirements so Im trying to write something myself.

The PHP that I have so far is just butchered from the fb developers centre example, and like I said I can successfully post to the wall but ONLY as myself.

I plan to set a CRON job up to execute the script and run through my RSS feed and update the fb fan page if there is something new. In light of this I will not be logged in to fb from the machine where this will be running (justhost server).

Also I dont seem to be able to call http get as I think it is disabled in the PHP config (which I cant change as Im on shared hosting). So Im stuck at the point in the fb dev centre help guides as [authenticating as a page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/) as I get a 'Call to undefined function http_get()' when Im trying to get the array of Pages and Applications that I manage in order to find out my 'page access token'. I have tried to use curl to return this but I cant have implimented it correctly as I just get "resource(4) of type (curl)" when I dump out the response using the following code:

```
//get user access token
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

//get page access token
$response  = curl_init("https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=".$access_token);
var_dump($response);
```

Even once I have this and can get this working in this instance, Im rather confused as to what is going to happen when this token expirse, and how it can be renewed without me having to edit this script every 2 hours or 60 days when the token expires.

Any help that anyone can give on getting this page access token and then keeping it alive when running from a script on a remote server via a CRON job would be very much appreciated.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
<?php

require '../src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'XXXHIDDENTHISXXX',
'secret' => 'XXXHIDDENTHISXXX',
'cookie' => true
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();



if ($user) {
try {
// Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
$user = null;
}
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
$params = array(
'scope' => 'publish_stream',
'redirect_uri' => 'http://autos.sevende.com.gt/rss_to_facebook/pages/'
);

if ($user) {
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($params);
} else {

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

}

//get user access token
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

//get page access token
$response  = curl_init("https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=".$access_token);
var_dump($response);

https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN

//set fanpage_id
$page_id = '234830586618763';

$attachment = array(

'link' => 'http://autos.sevende.com.gt/listing/565/');

$result = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/feed?access_token='.$access_token, 'post', $attachment);


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot post 'as' an application.

You can post as a user or as a page, but not as an application. The method for doing both of those is well documented, and the code you have above is close to the 'post as a page' instructions though